# How to find secrets in a Git repository?

Tags: security, git

I've been tasked to find secrets in a list of Git repositories.

A secret can be:

- A password
- An encryption key
- An API key
- A passphrase
- Anything else I may not like to see in plain text in the wild ;)

The objective is to find and rotate any secrets before these repositories are made public.

Is there any software that could help me out in this task?

Answer (score 1):

I decided to use [`git-secrets`](https://github.com/awslabs/git-secrets) from AWSLabs and wanted to share my experience.

---

*The canonical source for this example lives at https://github.com/customcommander/git-secrets-examples*

---

#### How To Install?

Fetch the latest release, unzip it and build it with Make. The git-secrets binary should now be in your PATH. e.g.,

```
curl -L -o /tmp/git-secrets.zip https://github.com/awslabs/git-secrets/archive/1.3.0.zip
cd /tmp
unzip git-secrets.zip
cd git-secrets-1.3.0
make install
```

You're not done yet! It now must be installed as a Git hook in each Git repository you would like to inspect. e.g.,

```
cd /path/to/repo
git-secrets --install
```

#### How To Find Secrets In A Git Repository?

We'll be looking for the following patterns:

- token
- username
- password

We want to know which files match these patterns in the current source tree and across the entire Git history.

To demonstrate the capabilities of `git-secrets` will add the first pattern from the CLI:

```
# at the root of the repo
git secrets --add token
```

The two other patterns will be loaded from a file `/var/forbidden-patterns.txt`:

```
username
password
```

```
# at the root of the repo
git secrets --add-provider -- cat /var/forbidden-patterns.txt
```

Now let's add the following files to our Git repo:

First `secrets-1.txt`:

```
username=abc
password=123
```

```
# at the root of your repo
git add secrets-1.txt
git commit -m "add secrets-1.txt"
# please note that we're now removing the file!
git rm secrets-1.txt
git commit -m "remove secrets-1.txt"
```

Then `secrets-2.txt`:

```
token=123456789
```

```
# at the root of your repo
git add secrets-2.txt
git commit -m "add secrets-2.txt"
```

Now let's scan the current source tree:

```
# at the root of your repo
git secrets --scan
```

Which outputs:

```
secrets-2.txt:1:token=123456789
```

It hasn't found `secrets-1.txt` because that file has been deleted. However we also want to make sure we're not exposing secrets in the Git history. Let's do that:

```
git secrets --scan-history
```

Which outputs:

```
c5e7f9887ed95f7d3aeb4ed011a8235e238b9ed1:secrets-2.txt:1:token=123456789
c0082ddbb0e2b14499808b376e133a6fbb5799cc:secrets-1.txt:1:username=abc
c0082ddbb0e2b14499808b376e133a6fbb5799cc:secrets-1.txt:2:password=123
```

We now can see in which commits a secret has been found.